# xv6 rev6 strange code in syscall()

Tags: c, unix, xv6

Any one can see why the following ifs, lines 3279-3285 in xv6-rev6 code,
are used:

```
int num;
num = proc−>tf−>eax;
if (num >= 0 && num < SYS_open && syscalls[num]) {
    proc−>tf−>eax = syscalls[num]();
} else if (num >= SYS_open && num < NELEM(syscalls) && syscalls[num]) {
    proc−>tf−>eax = syscalls[num]();
} else {...}
```

and not just:

```
int num;
num = proc−>tf−>eax;
if (num >= 0 && num < NELEM(syscalls) && syscalls[num]) {
   proc−>tf−>eax = syscalls[num]();
} else {...}
```

Comment: The two statements inside the `if` probably was different one time, but later changed. Is there a changelog of some kind you can check for the file (like like a CVS/SVN/GIT log?) Otherwise you have to ask the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer is below, which is partially right.

I took the liberty of contacting the authors at MIT and received the following response:

> The code in the second half of the `if` wrapped the system call in a `begin_trans/commit_trans`. We later moved the transaction start/end deeper into individual system calls, but forgot to fix `syscall()`.

So the two parts *were* different and, when they were changed to be the same, the modification simply didn't merge the two bits back together.

---

No, those two bits of code are equivalent.

It *may* be that at some point the calls to `syscalls[?]()` was different somehow, either with parameters or return locations but that's not the case now.

There may also have been a gap of some sort in there, something which may be supported by the fact there's a blank line at line 3115:

```
// System call numbers
#define SYS_fork         1
#define SYS_exit         2
#define SYS_wait         3
#define SYS_pipe         4
#define SYS_read         5
#define SYS_kill         6
#define SYS_exec         7
#define SYS_fstat        8
#define SYS_chdir        9
#define SYS_dup         10
#define SYS_getpid      11
#define SYS_sbrk        12
#define SYS_sleep       13
#define SYS_uptime      14

#define SYS_open        15
#define SYS_write       16
#define SYS_mknod       17
#define SYS_unlink      18
#define SYS_link        19
#define SYS_mkdir       20
#define SYS_close       21
```

This is the entire contents of `syscalls.h` and the blank line is somewhat suspicious.

There's no obvious functional grouping - though all the ones 15 and above seem to be related to file system manipulation, `SYS_read` and `SYS_fstat` are in the first group.

Maybe you should contact the authors to ask them (`6.828-staff at pdos.csail.mit.edu`).

I know (since I have the book) that it's not carried over from the Lions-era code since that has no such gaps in the list - they're also in a different order as well, with read and write next to each other for example.

Comment: The rev5-code has the shorter version. So I guess either it is a failed attempt at something, or preparation for something in the future.

Comment: @Morass, you may be right. v5 (http://www.scribd.com/doc/58105832/xv6-rev5) has only the single range check _and_ no gap in the header file. I've sent a note to the email address with a link to this question -they _may_ answer, who knows?